Check Geometrical Match of Two Scanned Images with Standard Linux Tools
I have two images (taken with a scanner at the same resolution) and I want to superimpose them on the screen to see how well two features match to each other after applying the right shift and rotation to one of them (like a combination of a front and the back side of a printed circuit board).
The two images are shifted and rotated with respect to each other with unknown parameters (dX, dY and rotation angle phi). In my case there are no straight outlines to calculate a matching corner or measure the relative rotation angle between the two scans.
In Gimp there are tools to flip images, to shift an image and to rotate them. One can superimpose one onto the other by using different layers and applying some degree of transparency to the uppermost layer. Using Gimp's Tools>Move and Tools>Rotate one after the other is very cumbersome.
There also is an uniform transformation tool in Gimp, but this one also interactively changes the size and applies other geometrical transformations, not only translation and rotation. I see nothing in them to pin the additional parameters.
I want to align the two images by visual inspection, shifting and rotating one of them (e.g. in 50% transparent mode) to the other one for a best fit.

Did I oversee the right tool in Gimp?
Or which other standard FOSS tool (and which function in it) do you
recommend for this purpose?


hm, I'm personally not aware of anything, but this would also be something you might be able to code together relatively easily. Are you any proficient in C++ or Python? Because then, you'd use OpenCV to load the images, and put them visually on-top of each other, and probably do something like read keyboard keys for movement and rotation. Also, you don't need straight outlines to compute a likely rotation / shift! There's other features in an image you can use, but going into a description of these might take this too far.

You might try mixing gimp with cli (command line) tools. For the rotation part you might try the imagemagick "unrotate" way to do this automatically as described in my answer to another question.  You can also easily use convert -flip -rotate 180 on an image before gimp. In gimp you could draw a red dot on each of the 2 scanned images, then in imagemagick superimpose the images at the dot point...
